# Error deploying my visual studio project in another computer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, installation, database-connection

I had a deployed visual project 2010 connected to sql and I had installed it in another computer but the database can't connect to the final project. I want to install it in other computers that will be connected to database. I think I have a problem in my connection:

```
 Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
                                               "Initial Catalog=enrollment")
```

Comment: 1. Put your connection into app.config
2. Create a form in your setup app and let user input new connection while installing the app. Then save new connection user just input into your config

Comment: sir can you give me example on this thanks

Comment: sir what if i install it in other computers have no sql server install is this also accessible ?

Comment: Yup, just provide the correct connection string to datatable

Comment: i can also use it as setup project only or a lan based not for web ?

Comment: What do you mean? Use what?

Answer (score 0):

The information provided at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171886%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will provide you with a good idea of how to manage connection strings in VS. The problem with your SqlConnection object is that your data source is still listed as 'localhost'. You need to change this to point to the location of your database.

Comment: sir what should been replace with localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the application should have a user friendly way of specifiying the settings for the connection, this will make connecting from different locations far easier and makes your application more portable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-string-during-installation) here will help you